# How to get the saved text file from my iOS App to PC?

Tags: ios, windows

I build an iOS App that collects data via BLE and saves it as text files. What I want to do now is to retrieve the saved data on my PC (Windows) for further analysis. As the developer I know I can download the App container via Xcode for accessing the saved file and it works well. However, I wonder if there’s any approach that I can get the saved files without using Xcode? Can I save the text files to a public location so I can access them directly?

Comment: `UIDocumentMenuViewController` lets you save to any installed and supported cloud storage locations; iCloud drive, drop box, OneDrive etc.

Comment: Email them to yourself?

Comment: You can send thoses file from by email, or upload them to a cloud/server ... But you can't access the client file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you can't do what you want in this exact way, as iOS devices do not support the USB mass storage protocol. The only way to get files out is using iTunes, which can access your iOS device's Documents folder.

Of course, you could reverse-engineer that protocol, but that's a bit unreliable and might break if Apple ever changes something.

Instead, find another way. E.g. you could have your PC app contain a tiny HTTP server and have your iOS app send an HTTP request to it that contains the file's data. Alternately you could even go via an actual server on the internet.

Or, given all iOS users have iCloud, you could also just save your data to iCloud, then have your PC users install Apple's iCloud for Windows stuff and then just access the file from there.

Comment: After changing the key “Application supports iTunes file sharing” to YES, I can then access Documents folder through iTunes directly, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to access the client's data on the PC.

You can create a file server or use a third party service like Amazon S3(https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

Client upload that collects data through the http/https protocol.
PC download the client's data and analysis.